# bootstrap width calculation issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this is a really weird thing and im sure there is an explanation (but it seems i cant figure it out on my own)

take the following code as an example :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="inner" id="large">large</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="inner" id="small">small</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the above code will lay two div's (each is 50% in width) and the second one is split again into two div's (again both 50% in width)

so this will make the second one (the smaller one) 1/2 the large one. 
but actually that doesn't happen the div with an `id="small"` is not exactly half the one with `id="large"`

i made a pen for this :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGMrMz

what id like to know is why such a behavior is happening and how to solve the issue preferably with no hacks.

Comment: i think it becasue each class "col-...-..." have their own left and right padding (15px or so) so unless you set style for those col padding=0 it will have space in there and the width will not as 1/2 as you want

Comment: [Add a no gutter class](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap is applying some padding and margins to `col-*` and `row`

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Everything is as expected.

Your row is `960px` wide inside you have a div with `col-xs-6` applied therefore you have a `480px` `div` with a `15px padding` left and right so your inner div is `480px-30px = 450px`.

Which is indeed not half of your first `div` but a bit less wider.

You can override those values. To do so I'll suggest you to do it in a separate css file and not in the bootstrap css directly therefore if you upgrade your bootstrap version you won't break your changes.

EDIT: regarding your comment, you have two times `col-xs-6` defined so the padding is applied twice

```
    <div class="col-xs-6">       // 930px + 30px from padding -> 960px
      <div class="row">          // 930px + 30px from negative margins -> 960px
        <div class="col-xs-6">   // 960px / 2 -> 480px
          <div class="inner" id="small">small<p>width : 450px</p></div>  // 480px - 30px padding from parent -> 450px
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Regards

Comment: well thats exactly my question if the larger one has a (width - 30px) and the smaller one has the same thing then the samller one should be exacly half the larger one ..

Comment: aha yeah i get it now .. dummy me with the stupid math inside my head .. thanks  ..

Comment: just a qiuck correction no the padding isnt applied twice, you got it wrong there because raw has -15 margin so the first padding is none existent

Comment: You're welcome please mark as answered if it satisfies you :) thanks !

Comment: I took longer and you even added a better explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally use .row to wrap each column. .row adds padding and margins.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row ">
   <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding ">
     <div class="inner" id="large">large</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
     <div class="row ">
       <div class="col-xs-6 nopadding">
         <div class="inner" id="small">small</div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

if you really wanted to remove the padding/margins, add a class to filter out the margins/paddings for each child column.

```
.nopadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waQGBB

Comment: thanks for the effort it's just i was doing math wrong :p .. any how thank you but i already accepted an answer

Comment: I was trying to figure how to solve this problem and i end up taking longer than @Aymeric . Btw, his explaination is better than mine though